# How to add social identity provider buttons to selfAsserted.html page in Azure B2C

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

This is related to question [How to create an email only page in Azure AD B2C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64163061/how-to-create-an-email-only-page-in-azure-ad-b2c)

I want to add the Facebook, Google and MSA social identity provider buttons to the selfAsserted.html page instead of the unified.html page.  These are my orchestration steps and technical profile:

```
<UserJourney Id="SignUpOrSignIn">
            <OrchestrationSteps>
                <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.selfasserted">
                    <ClaimsProviderSelections>
                        <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="FacebookExchange" />
                        <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="GoogleExchange" />
                        <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="MicrosoftAccountExchange" />
                    </ClaimsProviderSelections>
                    <ClaimsExchanges>
                        <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailOnlyExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-EmailOnly" />
                    </ClaimsExchanges>
                </OrchestrationStep>
                <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
                    <ClaimsProviderSelections>
                        <!--<ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="FacebookExchange" />
                        <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="GoogleExchange" />
                        <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="MicrosoftAccountExchange" />-->
                        <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
                    </ClaimsProviderSelections>
                    <ClaimsExchanges>
                        <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
                    </ClaimsExchanges>
                </OrchestrationStep>
...
</UserJourneys>

<TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-EmailOnly">
              <DisplayName>Local Account Signin</DisplayName>
              <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
              <Metadata>
                  <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted</Item>
              </Metadata>
              <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
              <OutputClaims>
                  <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" Required="true" />
              </OutputClaims>
              <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
          </TechnicalProfile>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only add IdP buttons on a combined sign in and sign up orchestration step or idpselections page..

OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">

Or

OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsProviderSelection" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.idpselections">

Comment: I replaced api.selfasserted with api.idpselections in my orchestration step and it didn't work.  I then replaced api.selfasserted with api.idpselections in both my orchestration step and technical profile and I still didn't see the providers.  Also, if I do get it to work, will I still be able to have the email field displayed with the social providers buttons?

Comment: Is the orchestration step type as per my example? It’ll display email + password and social providers, not just email as you set out to do. This is just the default from the starter pack.

Comment: As my linked post states, I don't want the password on the page.  Just email and idp buttons.

Comment: You can only have these 3 : 
1. Social IdP buttons + Username/Password - (combined sign in and sign up page)
2. Username + Password - (self asserted page or combined sign in and sign up page)
3. Buttons for all IdPs (Social + Local) - (combined sign in and sign up page or idpselection page)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the buttons to the selfasserted page by customizing the UI. Essentially you create a cshtml file based on the selfAsserted.cshtml template and either adjust the api.selfasserted ContentDefinition to use your new cshtml file (which needs to be hosted publicly - likely an Azure storage account), or you create a new ContentDefinition (based on the existing api.selfasserted ContentDefinition) that uses your new cshtml file, and adjust your orchestration step to use the new ContentDefinition.
To achieve these new buttons, you create claims in the custom policy to represent the buttons, enable the use of javascript in your relying party custom policy, and structure the cshtml appropriately.
This link touches on it a bit.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-custom-policy
And so does this one:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-and-page-layout?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

Within your cshtml you'd need something like this (this adds a Google and Microsoft button):

```
<!-- HTML -->
<button id="googleButton">Google</button>
<button id="microsoftButton">Microsoft</button>
 

<!-- JavaScript -->
<script>
document.getElementById('googleButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('googleClaim').value = 'true';
    document.getElementById('microsoftClaim').value = 'false';
    document.getElementById('continueButton').click(); // Simulate a click on the "Continue" button
});
 
document.getElementById('microsoftButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('googleClaim').value = 'false';
    document.getElementById('microsoftClaim').value = 'true';
    document.getElementById('continueButton').click(); // Simulate a click on the "Continue" button
});
</script>
```

In this example, the HTML code creates two buttons with the IDs “googleButton” and “microsoftButton” and googleClaim and microsoftClaim are the IDs of the HTML elements corresponding to your “google” and “microsoft” claims defined in the custom policy, and , continueButton is the ID of the “Continue” button. The javascript includes a Continue button press if the new buttons are pressed b/c the Continue button has to be pressed to move to the next step in the user journey.

Keep in mind that this is not the only code needed in your HTML file to make this work, but the pieces needed to get the buttons to show and allow proper interaction and relaying of the values (true or false) to the corresponding claims.

Also, while it is talking about customizing the HTML for a user flow instead of custom policy, the information in this link is still helpful:
https://dev.to/425show/customize-the-look-and-feel-of-your-azure-ad-b2c-page-30m6

Hope this helps.